# Deserialize (parse) JSON array as System.Array of Object

Tags: .net, json, json.net

The following code shows that JSON.NET deserializes arrays as `List<object>`, but I want `object[]` instead. Is it possible?

```
> ((dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>("{ \"foo\": 1, bar: [5, 6] }")).bar.GetType().FullName
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"
```

Comment: You could create your own version of [`ExpandoObjectConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/ExpandoObjectConverter.cs) that constructs arrays instead of lists.  Just do `return list.ToArray();` around [line 106](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/ExpandoObjectConverter.cs#L106).

Comment: Yes, you could simply use the ToArray() method or there is any particular reason you want to do it in one single line (BTW which looks awful)

Comment: Or create a class which defines the `bar` property as `object[]` and deserialize to that instead of `ExpandoObject`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.ToArray();` on the returned  serialized object. Alternatively you could use  [`DeserializeObject(String value, Type type)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm) to try to *enforce* the type of the returned object.